# Render html to racket gui

Tags: html, user-interface, racket

I'm trying to write a WYSIWYG text editor that allows me to write text in the top window, and have the resulting scribble text rendered in the bottom window. I figured the way I would do this would be to call `scribble myfile.rkt` in the background periodically, and then render the resulting output to a bottom screen using [render-html-to-text](https://docs.racket-lang.org/browser/index.html?q=render-html-to-text#%28def._%28%28lib._browser%2Fhtmltext..rkt%29._render-html-to-text%29%29). I'm having some trouble getting the render to work. Based on the documentation I need

```
  in : input-port?
  dest : (is-a? html-text<%>)
  load-img? : any/c
  eval-rkt? : any/c
```

The relevant parts of my script look like this

```
#lang racket/gui
(require racket/os racket/runtime-path "init.rkt" 
         browser/htmltext)
(require browser)


(define f (new frame% [label (~a "Dremacs" "@" (gethostname))]
                      [width 960]
                      [height 540]))



(define new-cnv (new cnv% [parent f]))


(send t insert ";; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; To create a file, visit it with C-x C-f and enter text in its buffer.")
(send new-cnv set-editor t)

(define html-renderer%
  (interface (html-text<%>)))



(define viewer (new panel%
                    [parent f]
                    [min-width 300]
                    [min-height 300]))



(render-html-to-text (open-input-file "TODO.html") html-renderer% #t #t)

(send f show #t)
```

But I get the error

```
render-html-to-text: expects argument of type <html-text<%> object>; given: '(#<input-port:/home/diego/repos/dremacs/dremacs/TODO.html> #<interface:html-renderer%>)
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/pkgs/drracket/browser/htmltext.rkt:61:0: render-html-to-text
   "/home/diego/repos/dremacs/dremacs/editor.rkt": [running body]
   temp37_0
```

And I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html-renderer% is not created correctly.

Use html-text-mixin to turn a text% into something that handles html-text.

But ... don't expect too much from the html-renderer.
It's old and doesn't support stylesheets.
Back in the day it was used to display documentation for DrRacket.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that. Are there any alternatives? If not I could try to figure out how to roll my own!

Comment: There are a few attempts to embed webkit, but I haven't tried them.